# how to apply a function on all possible combination

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10, ncol=10))
```

I want to calculate and extract all possible p-values between all columns 
if I want to do this between two of them, I do this

```
wilcox.test(df$X1,df$X2, paired=TRUE)
```

and it gives me

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  df$X1 and df$X2
V = 21, p-value = 0.5566
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

I want to have the V and p-value between all possible pairs column-wise

e.g. Column1 with Column 2

Column1 with Column 3

column1 with column 4  etc etc

The output I want to have

```
X1-X2 : V p-value
X1-X2 : V p-value
.
.
.
```

Comment: Try with `combn(names(df), 2, FUN = function(x) paste(paste(x, collapse='-'), wilcox.test(df[,x[1]], df[,x[2]], paired = TRUE)$p.value, sep=" : "))`

Comment: It gives all the pairwise combinations.  I edited the code to have the column names as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `combn` on the `names` of the 'df' specifying the number of elements to choose i.e. `m` as 2, subset the columns of the dataset, apply `wilcox.test`, extract the `p.value` and `paste` with the column names to get the expected format

```
combn(names(df), 2, FUN = function(x) paste(paste(x, collapse='-'), 
       wilcox.test(df[,x[1]], df[,x[2]], paired = TRUE)$p.value, sep=" : "))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*10), nrow=10, ncol=10))
```

Comment: there are  There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: @nik Your example was not good.  Please use the example I showed in my post.  You had repeated elements because you got only `rnorm(20)` while the number of observations were 100 i.e. 10x10 and this created the pvalue to become NaN